# How to make logics for field with GROUP BY / Can I use text field as SQL logic?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm stacked here :

```
SELECT [RecTime], [Name],
   CAST(CASE WHEN 
   -- <logics>
    1=0 -- ???
    -- </logics>
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [Value]
FROM EventIncidentsStates
GROUP BY [RecTime], [Name]
```

EventIncidentsStates is looking like this :

```
        RecTime                    SQL                Event        Name       Val
2011-03-02 08:36:10.047 | Alarm1002 AND Alarm1004 | Alarm1002 | doubleAlarm  | 1
2011-03-02 08:36:10.047 | Alarm1002 AND Alarm1004 | Alarm1004 | doubleAlarm  | 0
2011-03-02 08:36:10.047 | Alarm1002               | Alarm1002 | myalarm1002  | 1
2011-03-02 08:36:20.030 | Alarm1002 AND Alarm1004 | Alarm1002 | doubleAlarm  | 1
2011-03-02 08:36:20.030 | Alarm1002 AND Alarm1004 | Alarm1004 | doubleAlarm  | 0
2011-03-02 08:36:20.030 | Alarm1004               | Alarm1004 | TestIncident | 0
2011-03-02 08:36:40.050 | Alarm1002 AND Alarm1004 | Alarm1002 | doubleAlarm  | 0
2011-03-02 08:36:40.050 | Alarm1002 AND Alarm1004 | Alarm1004 | doubleAlarm  | 0
2011-03-02 08:36:40.050 | Alarm1004               | Alarm1004 | TestIncident | 0
```

Val is value of Event, not a value of Name, Value of Name I need to get with SQL logic and grouping.

ehh let me time to explain what is it by example of first node ,

first field is RecTime, second one is **Alarm1002 AND Alarm1004** this must be a logics :) that also could be looking alike  **(Alarm1002 = 1 AND Alarm1004 = 1)** , not sure if I can use it , **doubleAlarm** is ***Name*** , the name of my complex event with this logics,

even there is events for this time,

```
Alarm1002 is 1
Alarm1004 is 0
```

So [Value] of **doubleAlarm** should be (1 AND 0) = 0 ... I know that my structure a bit weird but the task was very complex :)

and after all this question contains 2 questions , I would be happy to get answer on any :

1. how to use custom logic with GROUP BY
2. how to parse nvarchar field to SQL logics , yes second question is kind of headache

   Another example :

   ```
   -- Example
       SELECT [RecTime], [Name],
          CAST(CASE WHEN 
          -- <logics>
          [SQL]
          -- </logics>
          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [Value]
       FROM EventIncidentsStates
       GROUP BY [RecTime], [Name], [SQL]



   -- Inital data

   EventIncidentsStates -

   [RecTime]         [SQL]                [EventName] [Value] [Name]
   SomeDate (EVENT1 = 1 AND EVENT2 = 1)     EVENT1       1      Some
   SomeDate (EVENT1 = 1 AND EVENT2 = 1)     EVENT2       0      Some

   -- Out data

   SomeDate Some 0
   ```

Comment: The table looked a bit messy with tabs as field delimiters. I've replaced the tabs and aligned the columns accordingly. Please verify if the table now looks as intended. (It certainly looks better, but maybe wrong, I'm just not sure.)

Comment: Maybe some columns should be removed, but at least their names at the top could be helpful.

Comment: >>"I know that my structure a bit weird but the task was very complex", can you tell a bit more, what the task was, maybe there is a simpler way? Also I'm not quite sure I understand where Alarm1002 and Alarm1004 come from. You wrote, that Alarm1002 is 1 and Alarm1004 is 0. What there is Alarm445 in the "logic" how do you know if it 1 or 0 then?

Comment: @zespri it comes from EventIncidentsStates , the Event is Alarm1002 or Alarm1004 in some time and Val is 1 or 0. And I need to calculate "SQL" (logics) for them in this time.

Comment: I think I now understand the entire scheme. So, what you are actually after is *evaluating* of the expressions stored in the `SQL` column. Event names are sort of variables, and their values must first be collected from different rows before evaluating the entire expression. Did you say the task was complex? Oh no, it's not. It's enormous!

Comment: Your sample data contain a record of a complex event that seems to happen (or be recorded) twice at the same point of time, namely at `2011-03-02 08:36:20.030`, and the event is `doubleAlarm`. Is that an actually possible case? It might complicate the task even further. How should we distinguish the two `Alarm1002` values for the same complex event of `doubleAlarm`, if their recorded times are absolutely identical?

Comment: @Andriy M ... now I've got all Events and their values in one View , in same fields, and the logics so I just need to group them to complex events by parsing the logics.

Comment: @Andriy M , yes ... that means my previous view made Error , I checked it's really got a big bug I need to fix :(

Comment: All right, so it was not supposed to be like that, was it?

Comment: @Andriy M yes , I fixed it but a bit changed a structure ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asn to first question

Make use of [Case.. when](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) amy resolve your issue

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT JobTitle, MAX(ph1.Rate)AS MaximumRate
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS ph1 ON e.BusinessEntityID = ph1.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY JobTitle
HAVING (MAX(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' 
        THEN ph1.Rate 
        ELSE NULL END) > 40.00
     OR MAX(CASE WHEN Gender  = 'F' 
        THEN ph1.Rate  
        ELSE NULL END) > 42.00)
ORDER BY MaximumRate DESC;
```

Comment: yes, I just wanted to know how use it with values FROM EventIncidentsStates (my view) where I'm doing group by, when I use MAX() or another function I don't need to know other values there, but I need to know other fields from EventIncidentsStates , I need to know some Event names and Event Values from it.